# RotatingFileHandler writing to a different folder for backup

Tags: python, logging

I am working with Python logger, creating a log file (`/opt/feedlog.log`)

I am specifically trying to create a backup folder to archive the old log files

`/opt/archive`

would contain

```
/opt/archive/feedlog.log.1
/opt/archive/feedlog.log.2
/opt/archive/feedlog.log.3
```

Below is my sample code :

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('feed_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler('/opt/feedlog.log', maxBytes=1000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10000):
        logger.warning('Hello world !!!')
```

Is there any way I could force the `RotatingFileHandler` to create backup files at a different folder `archive` , rather than original folder.

Any inputs would be helpful !

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, how did you manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be to create a function to do this and pass it as `rotator` argument to `RotatingFileHandler`.
The other way would be to create your own version of `RotatingFileHandler`. It should be easier then it sound. Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler All you need is create your own class inheriting from this one and override `rotate`.

```py
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

class MyRotatingFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    # copied from python source
    def rotate(self, source, dest): # change the destination here
        if not callable(self.rotator):
            # Issue 18940: A file may not have been created if delay is True.
            if os.path.exists(source):
                os.rename(source, dest)
        else:
            self.rotator(source, dest)
```